# How to get running Gatsby page query data with React Context API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, graphql, gatsby

I'm working on a site where I have a gallery and custom build lightbox. Currently, I'm querying my data with a page query, however, I also use them in other components to display the right images and changing states. It is easier for me to store states in Context API as my data flow both-ways (I need global state) and to avoid props drilling as well.

I've setup my context.provider in **gatsby-ssr.js** and **gatsby-browser.js** like this:

```
const React = require("react");
const { PhotosContextProvider } = require("./src/contexts/photosContext");

exports.wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
    return <PhotosContextProvider>{element}</PhotosContextProvider>;

};
```

I've followed official gatsby documentation for wrapping my root component into context provider.

**Gallery.js** here I fetch my data and set them into global state:

```
import { usePhotosContext } from "../contexts/photosContext";

const Test = ({ data }) => {
    const { contextData, setContextData } = usePhotosContext();


useEffect(() => {
    setContextData(data);
}, [data]);


return (
    <div>
        <h1>hey from test site</h1>
            {contextData.allStrapiCategory.allCategories.map((item) => (
            <p>{item.name}</p>
        ))}
     <OtherNestedComponents />  
    </div>
);
};

export const getData = graphql`
    query TestQuery {
        allStrapiCategory(sort: { fields: name }) {
            allCategories: nodes {
                name
            }
        }
    }
`;

export default Test;
```

**NOTE:** This is just a test query for simplicity

I've double-checked if I get the data and for typos, and everything works, but the problem occurs when I try to render them out. I get type error undefined. I think it's because it takes a moment to setState so on my first render the contextData array is empty, and after the state is set then the component could render.

Do you have any idea how to work around this or am I missing something? Should I use a different type of query? I'm querying all photos so I don't need to set any variables.

**EDIT:** I've found a solution for this kinda, basically I check if the data exits and I render my component conditionally.

```
return testData.length === 0 ? (
    <div className="hidden">
        <h2>Hey from test</h2>
        <p>Nothing to render</p>
    </div>
) : (
    <div>
        <h2>Hey from test</h2>
        {testData.allStrapiCategory.allCategories.map((item) => (
            <p>{item.name}</p>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

However, I find this hacky, and kinda repetitive as I'd have to use this in every component that I use that data at. So I'm still looking for other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing this [page queried] data to root provider doesn't make a sense [neither in gatsby nor in apollo] - data duplication, not required in all pages/etc.

... this data is **fetched at build time** then no need to check length/loading/etc

... you can render provider in page component to pass data to child components using context (without props drilling).

Comment: I'm sorry may you include a code, my English isn't the best I'm not sure if I understand you correctly.

Comment: what use case/structure/components/pages? where data passed/used? it's not clear, too

Comment: I ve got portfolio.js file in /pages directory, here I fetch my data. In this site I render out some header, text and my other component gallery.js.

Gallery.js component consumes queried data. Here I have another component lightbox.js which is my custom lightbox, this component recieves ID of currently selected image, all images (queried data) and filtered photos.

And depending on currently selected filter (photo categories) in gallery.js I change filtered photos array, and set my nextPhoto and prevPhoto.

Comment: There is no complexity here, just pass data as props ... where is the problem?

Comment: For example I need to update currentPhotoId which comes from gallery.js to lightbox.js as a props. And I'm updating it in lightbox.js. Thats why I want to use global state.

Comment: still only one value, only one level up, parent? pass setter as prop? ... why gallery should know current photo? it's internal lightbox component data ... better example?

Comment: That was just an example I plan to build it a little bit more, also I'm asking for future projects as well as I'm really curious about this issue.

Well I need to get that setter from sowhere. Gallery knows current photo because I have my filters and filteredPhotos there, also my event listener for click when user click on photo to select it so I set my currentId photo there. Then I just pass currentPhotoId to lightbox.

Comment: Yea and one more thing, gatsby-image doesnt allow you to set your own data- HTML attribue, nor ID, but there is a little trick Ive found and I set it using className, then on click I filter out classes and get that ID  which is my currentPhotoId, and as I display my photos in gallery it makes sense to set it there as well.

Comment: as in answer, just create (in gallery page component) and render lightbox wrapped into context provider, lightbox and any nested child can use this context (basic context usage) ... you can 'decorate' queried data before usage/passing down to rendered components - no [css] tricks required, react is data-driven - just change/postprocess data